# How to pass a variable to create and HtmlBody with python and win32

Tags: python, html, string, html-email, win32com

what im tryng to do is send a birthday notification, everything is working fine, But
i want to pass the name of the Birthday Person to show it in the HTML, Per example in Subject
what i have is: Happy Birthday test1 (Where test1 is the result of a loop in the database)
i want to use test1 (name) again in the HTML. To show: Today is your Day Test1! (in the HTML, because i need to format to make it look nice)

Below is my code and

```
def email_func(subject, birthday_receiver, name):
    mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    mailItem.BodyFormat = 1
    mailItem.To = 'receiver@magmia.com'
    mailItem.Cc = email
    mailItem.Subject = subject+' '+str(name)+'!'+' '+str(month)+'/'+str(day)
    mailItem.htmlBody = '''
        <h1>Today is your Day</h1>
        <img src="E:\\Birthday Notification\\happy-birthday3.png" alt="birthday">
        <img src="E:\\Birthday Notification\\Signature.png" alt="signature" width="300" 
           height="200">
         <style>
        h1 {
            text-shadow: 1px 1px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 40px;
            color: navy;
            }
          </style>
      '''
```

Theres any option to do this in python:

```
def email_func(subject, birthday_receiver, name):
    mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    mailItem.BodyFormat = 1
    mailItem.To = 'receiver@magmia.com'
    mailItem.Cc = email
    mailItem.Subject = subject+' '+str(name)+'!'+' '+str(month)+'/'+str(day)
    mailItem.htmlBody = '''
      '''
         <h1>Today is your Day {{ str(name) }}</h1>
         <img src="E:\\Birthday Notification\\happy-birthday3.png" alt="birthday">
         <img src="E:\\Birthday Notification\\Signature.png" alt="signature" width="300" 
            height="200">
         <style>
         h1 {
             text-shadow: 1px 1px;
             text-align: center;
             font-family: sans-serif;
             font-size: 40px;
             color: navy;
            }
          </style>
       '''
```

Thank you for the Help

Comment: You can do the string addition, just like you did in the subject, or a better plan is to use "f-strings".  Example, `Subject = f"{subject} {name}!  {month}/{day}"`.  You can do the same with `f'''`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the HTML in a string, then concatenate in any variables you want to add. You can use parentheses to make the strings multiline

```
def email_func(subject, birthday_receiver, name):
    mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    mailItem.BodyFormat = 1
    mailItem.To = 'receiver@magmia.com'
    mailItem.Cc = email
    mailItem.Subject = subject+' '+str(name)+'!'+' '+str(month)+'/'+str(day)
    mailItem.htmlBody = ('''
        "<h1>Today is
        '''
        + str(name) + 
        '''
        your Day</h1>
        <img src="E:\\Birthday Notification\\happy-birthday3.png" alt="birthday">
        <img src="E:\\Birthday Notification\\Signature.png" alt="signature" width="300" 
           height="200">
         <style>
        h1 {
            text-shadow: 1px 1px;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 40px;
            color: navy;
            }
          </style>"
          ''')
```

Here is perhaps a prettier way to do it:

```
htmlBody = (
        "<h1>Today is" + str(name) + "'s Day</h1>" +
        "<img src='E:\\Birthday Notification\\happy-birthday3.png' alt='birthday'>" +
        "<img src='E:\\Birthday Notification\\Signature.png' alt='signature' width='300' " +
           "height='200'>" +
         "<style>" +
        "h1 {" +
            "text-shadow: 1px 1px;" +
            "text-align: center;" +
            "font-family: sans-serif;" +
            "font-size: 40px;" +
            "color: navy;" +
            "}" +
          "</style>"
          )
```